# values of input text fields in a html multipart form

Tags: java, file-upload, apache-commons

I use Apache Commons FileUpload in a java server-side app that has a html form with fields :

1. a destination fied that will be
   filled with email address of the
   destination mailbox
2. a message text with a message of the sender
3. a `<input type=file ...` field for uploading a photo.
   I can receive uploaded file (as a stream) but how I can access 1) and 2) form values (completed by the user of app)?
   Many thanks,
   Aurel

Answer (score 8):

I am guessing you are using a FileItemIterator to iterate the items in the request. The iterators next() method returns a FileItemStream (not a FileItem). Open the stream on that object and turn it into a string like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams;
...
FileItemStream item = iterator.next();
InputStream stream = item.openStream();
String name = item.getFieldName();
String value = Streams.asString(stream);
```

The getString method suggested by other answers is a method on the FileItem interface.

Answer (score 6):

You can receive them using the same API. Just hook on when [`FileItem#isFormField()`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#isFormField%28%29) returns `true`. If it returns `false` then it's an uploaded file as you probably already are using.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
        for (FileItem item : items) {
            if (item.isFormField()) {
                // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
                String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                String fieldvalue = item.getString();
                // ... (do your job here)
            } else {
                // Process form file field (input type="file").
                String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
                InputStream filecontent = item.getInputStream();
                // ... (do your job here)
            }
        }
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        throw new ServletException("Cannot parse multipart request.", e);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question but I cannot use item.getString , because getString is not a method in FileItem class or its ancestors ... Please show me how I deal with this

Comment: It is definitely in the API http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#getString%28%29 Apparently you're not using Apache Commons FileUpload at all?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I am using for this purpose:

`public static Hashtable getParamsFromMultipartForm(HttpServletRequest req) throws FileUploadException {
        Hashtable ret = new Hashtable();
        List items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(req);
        for (FileItem item : items) {
            if (item.isFormField()) {
                ret.put(item.getFieldName(), item.getString());
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }`

And then, whenever i need the value of any of my params, i just write, say:

`//at the beginning of a servlet
Hashtable multipartParams = TheClassWhereIPutThatMethod.getParamsFromMultipartForm(req);`

String myParamFromForm = multipartParams.get("myParamFromForm");

Answer (score 1):

So, what I did is to use the instance of fileItem as in:

```
Hashtable incoming = new Hashtable();
fileName = sfu.parseRequest(request);

//iterating over each uploaded file and storing the values of different parameters in the HashTable (incoming)

for(FileItem f:fileName)
                    {
                    incoming.put(f.getFieldName(), f.getString()); 
                    }
//utilizing that HashTable and getting the value of desired field in the below manner, as in my case i required the value of "permissions" from the jsp page

             for(FileItem f:fileName)
                    {
                        String role= (String)incoming.get("permission"); //as it is a multipart form request, so need to get using this
                    }
```

Thanks